# Getting Error in while downloading Git Clone?

Tags: macos, git, clone

I am opening the terminal, writting the command as follows

```
 git clone url
```

It says as

```
Cloning into code.xyz.com...
```

and I am getting error

```
    error: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details:
    error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed while accessing https://code.xyz.com/info/refs

    fatal: HTTP request failed
```

I am using Mac OS X 10.7, can anyone guide me what should I do, I have proper username and password, and correct url?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you do not have any of Certification Authority certificates installed on your system.

Ignore ssl certificate verification and proceed with the installation:

```
$ env GIT_SSL_NO_VERIFY=true git clone https://github...
```

Or you can try this for MAC oS :

```
git config --global --add http.sslVerify false
```

Comment: that error solved, but now getting this fatal: https://code.ubanquity.com/info/refs not found: did you run git update-server-info on the server?

Comment: I got this link, see this for new error http://serverfault.com/questions/114711/fatal-http-myserverip-home-git-example-git-info-refs-not-found-did-you-run-g

Comment: Accepted your answer, let me guide if you know the about new error @Mithun

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the https and just using http in the clone url.

Comment: https://code.abc.com/, for suppose it is my URL, then what should I write command using Mac OS X Terminal?